# Macro to fill blank selected row from in main workbook from open workbook form

Tags: vba, excel

I have one main workbook I use as a schedule. I have a different "request" excel workbook form that customers send to me filled out. I want to have a macro that copies one row from the customer form into my main workbook. In my main workbook, I want to manually enter a new row, have that row selected, and then the data from the customer workbook would fill into the selected row. I have many of the customer forms and would prefer the macro to pull the data from whatever customer form I have open at that time. I do not want the macro to automatically insert a new row because of the way I have my schedule workbook formatted. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thank you!

EDIT: I tried to run an initial macro and here is the code:

```
    Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Windows("TEST - Tool Move Request Form.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B12:K12").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("TEST - Ocotillo Site Tool Move Schedule.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A26").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("E32").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you attempted any of the code yourself? If so, can you please post it.  If not, I'd recommend starting by using the Macro Recorder (found by enabling the Developer Tab under File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon).

I would like to see what you have attempted so far and then we can build off of it from there!

Comment: Hi @Busse! I am really a noob at this stuff but I did try recording one macro. It only barely accomplishes what I'm trying to do. Here it is:     
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Windows("TEST - Tool Move Request Form.xlsx").Activate
    Range("B12:K12").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("TEST - Ocotillo Site Tool Move Schedule.xlsx").Activate
    Range("A26").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("E32").Select
End Sub

Comment: Also, in the request form I have some cells that are merged, and in my main workbook they are not. I would want the macro to ignore the cells that are merged ones and just paste as one in the main workbook.

Comment: Not a problem, everyone has to start somewhere.  Do me a favor and place edit your original post and place the code you just created in there (using the code brackets!). As you may have noticed, it's near impossible to read when they are pasted in comments.

Comment: Thank you @Busse I just posted it

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Macro1()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim PrevRow As Long

'Workbook From - Take the path
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\TEST - Tool Move Request Form.xlsx")
'Workbook To - Take the path
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\TEST - Ocotillo Site Tool Move Schedule.xlsx")
'Find the last row and move to the next row
PrevRow = y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

'Take the sheet you're going to, and add corresponding value
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & PrevRow).Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B12")
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & PrevRow).Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C12")
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & PrevRow).Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D12")
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & PrevRow).Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E12")
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & PrevRow).Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F12")
y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & PrevRow).Value = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G12")
End Sub
```